# Can not set OnListItemClick on Tab Activity

Tags: android, android-listview, tabs

I want to do an activity with tab bar, and i have 5 tab menus. The MainActivity includes Tabhost like that;

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String tab_title[] = { "Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3", "Tab 4", "Tab 5" };

    int tab_drawables[] = { R.drawable.menu_bookmark,
            R.drawable.menu_filemanager, R.drawable.menu_download,
            R.drawable.menu_sharepage, R.drawable.menu_about };

    Object tab_act[] = { Tab1.class, Tab2.class, Tab3.class, Tab4.class, Tab5.class };

    final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec tab_spec;

    for (int i = 0; i < tab_act.length; i++) {
        tab_spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tab_title[i]);
        tab_spec.setIndicator(tab_title[i],
                getResources().getDrawable(tab_drawables[i]));
        tab_spec.setContent(new Intent(this, (Class<?>) tab_act[i]));
        tabHost.addTab(tab_spec);
    }
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

When i click on Tab2, Tab2.java class will be called. This class has a listview. I want to play music on youtube when i click on list item. My code is working but OnListItemClick method is not working.

```
public class Tab2 extends Activity{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;
Context context ;
Bitmap bitmap;

public static String title[] = { "song 1", "song 2", "song 3"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    data = new Vector<RowData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
        try {
                rd = new RowData(i, title[i]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        data.add(rd);
    }
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.activity_list_view, R.id.title, data);
}

private class RowData {
    protected int mId;
    protected String mTitle;

    RowData(int id, String title) {
        mId = id;
        mTitle = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mId + " " + mTitle;
    }
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (position == 0) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK8mJJJvaes")));
    }
    else if (position == 1) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWyEEj2pSt0")));
    }   
    else if (position == 2){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWyEEj2pSt0")));
    }
}

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        TextView title = null;
        RowData rowData = getItem(position);
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.activity_list_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        title = holder.gettitle();
        title.setText(rowData.mTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private View mRow;
        private TextView title = null;
        private ImageView i11 = null;

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            mRow = row;
        }

        public TextView gettitle() {
            if (null == title) {
                title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
            }
            return title;
        }

    }   
}
```

}

I have no problem with the layouts, i m sure about that so no need to show my xml files. :)

**Updated**

I change Tab2 class with following codes;

```
public class Tab2 extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;
Context context ;
Bitmap bitmap;

public static String title[] = { "song 1", "song 2", "song 3"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    data = new Vector<RowData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
        try {
                rd = new RowData(i, title[i]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        data.add(rd);
    }
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.activity_list_view, R.id.title, data);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private class RowData {
    protected int mId;
    protected String mTitle;

    RowData(int id, String title) {
        mId = id;
        mTitle = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mId + " " + mTitle;
    }
}


private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        TextView title = null;
        RowData rowData = getItem(position);
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.activity_list_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        title = holder.gettitle();
        title.setText(rowData.mTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private View mRow;
        private TextView title = null;
        private ImageView i11 = null;

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            mRow = row;
        }

        public TextView gettitle() {
            if (null == title) {
                title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
            }
            return title;
        }

    }   
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (position == 0) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jHrdLUFA-8")));
    }
    else if (position == 1) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HMfKUtYHog")));
    }   
    else if (position == 2){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7beBw8uQOR8")));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? Pleas post `LogCat` / `Stack Traces` / `etc`.

Comment: All list items is shown, but OnListItemClick method is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public class Tab2 extends Activity

`Tab2` extends Activity, not `ListActivity`.

To get this working, find `ListView` widget in `R.layout.tab2`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tab2);    

mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

data = new Vector<RowData>();
for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
    try {
            rd = new RowData(i, title[i]);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    data.add(rd);
}

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
        R.layout.activity_list_view, R.id.title, data);

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_listiew_id);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Change your class definition to:

```
public class Tab2 extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

And change `onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)` to:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick((AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

The problem with your code is that you never assign an `OnItemClickListener` to the `ListView`. And if you want to use `onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`, then `Tab2` should extend `ListActivity`, not `Activity`. To see why: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29).

Comment: I added my ListView widget from tab2.xml, but i can not run that method. Your solutions are not working for me :(

Comment: I changed @vikram, you can see that i follow your suggestions.

Comment: @Droid You are right. The changes are correct and should have solved the problem. Put a Log statement inside `onItemClick(....)` above `if (position == 0)`: `Log.i("onItemClick", "Click resgistered")`. Then start `Tab 2` activity and click on any item. Does the `info` perspective in Logcat show `Click resgistered`?

Comment: The program never comes the method OnItemClick. There is no action with clicking on any item. I can not understand that problem. Any usefull ideas?

Comment: @Droid The thing is: I just tried your code. And it works. A chooser window open on list item click, with two options: Chrome and Youtube. Not sure what to tell you here. Clean your project. Restart eclipse. And give it another try. Recheck your xml files. If it still doesn't work, post your xml files. May be I can spot something in them.

Comment: I solved that problem now that method is working properly. I can not understand my mistake but when i understand, i will commend here. Thanks to your exertions.